# Encontrar Função Javascript (onchange)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

tenho uma duvida. Quero fazer uma caixa de seleções dependes em uma pagina utilizando razor e javascript. TIPO, ao selecionar a comunidade, tem que aparecer as pessoas correspondes a ela. Mas não consigo chamar a função com o onchange. Podem me ajudar ? Teria algum outro jeito de fazer isso ? (sem usar Json)

O código abaixo :

```
    <script language="JavaScript"></script>


<title></title>
```

```
<!--Adiciona as comunidades existentes numa lista-->
@{

    List<String> comunidades = new List<String>();
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Distinct [nom_Comunidade] FROM [COB].[dbo].[TB_M] 
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comunidades.Add(dr.GetString(0));
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}


<!--Usa os valores da lista numa caixa de opções-->


<select name="teste" id="teste" onchange="test(this.value);">
    @{ foreach (string rt in comunidades)
        {
            <option>@rt</option>
        }
    }
</select>



<script language="javascript">


              function test1(valor)
            {
                //var thing = document.getElementById("teste").value;
                var thing = valor;

                @{
                    String thing2 = Request["teste"];
                    List<String> all_rt = new List<String>();
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Distinct [nom_pessoa] FROM [COB].[dbo].[TB_M] where [nom_Comunidade] = '" + thing2 +"'" ;
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            all_rt.Add(dr.GetString(0));
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();

                    foreach (string r in all_rt)
                    {
                        <text>
                        <select>
                            @foreach (string rt in all_rt)
                            {
                                <option>@rt</option>
                              }
                        </select>
                        </text>

                    }

                }

            }


</script>
```

Comment: Você está chamando a função "test", mas no código tem uma função "test1", é isso mesmo?

Comment: Os blocos de server scripts vão rodar apenas antes da resposta ao browser...

Comment: @LeonardoL , o certo é os 2 teste 1. Ta assim pq da ultima vez eu fui tentar fazer uma gambiarra haha.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, como faço pra que ele rode só depois da resposta na pagina?

Comment: Não faz, você deveria criar uma rota para ela no servidor e buscar os valores via Ajax... ou vai ter que ficar recarregando a página. Acho que você vai ter que repensar toda a sua solução e estudar um pouco sobre a plataforma que está utilizando.

Comment: ou.... você popula um objeto javascript com todo o conteúdo só de uma vez e interage com ele...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Da pra fazer o o ajax conversar com o razor? E outra duvida, o objeto eu teria que criar num arquivo js à parte ou posso criar ele no proprio cshtml da pagina?

Comment: Cara, você pode fazer o que quiser e como quiser, mas isso não quer dizer que será uma boa opção e principalmente se deveria ser feito. O meu conselho é que você dê um passo atrás, estude mais e entenda o que você está fazendo.